# How to make a runnable jar point to a different JRE,Maven?

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I created an app and I turn it to a runnable Jar ! so in order to run it user need to install java, javafx and maven. and to avoid that I put my runnable jar, a copy of maven file and a copy of java file together in one folder ! now All I need is : how to make my runnable jar point to those maven and java as main jre so the user simply use those ! no need to install java or maven for him ?

Comment: Unless your application has anything to do with maven (i.e. it's not simply an "app made with maven") why would you think you need to embed maven with your app?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca my app basically create maven projects ! so the user need to have maven and java and javafx in his desktop so he can use it

Comment: Usually you put a bat or sh file into the project that starts the jar with the right parameters and the correct JDK.

Comment: @JFMeier exactly ! but how to configure this bat/sh file ! I heard about the Launch4j but I did not how to configure the output file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have something like this( bat file example):

```
@echo off
@setlocal

set JAVA_HOME="your_path_to_jre"
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%


java  -cp .;extra_libs_you_need/*;  com.example.YourMainClass
```